# Javascript code with gmap and ionic framework

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic-framework

I have a page that show a map (`ShowMap.html`) with this extracted code:

```
<div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
```

In the controller I use something like this:

```
...
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
...
```

and the map is shown fine.

From that page I have a button where an `ng-click` activates a function that 
go to another view with code like this:

```
$state.go("Details",
           {
             searchTerm: term
           });
```

then from `Details.html` I have another button with another `ng-click` and another function that came back to `ShowMap.html`:

```
$state.go("ShowMap",
           {
             data: d
           });
```

at this point the map is not shown anymore.

It seems like it is disappeared. In fact inside the map div nothing is rendered.

Why? It seems like state change from `$state` cause some problem to map...

Answer (score 1):

Convenience method for transitioning to a new state. `$state.go` calls `$state.transitionTo` internally but automatically sets options to `{ location: true, inherit: true, relative: $state.$current, notify: true }`. This allows you to easily use an absolute or relative to path and specify only the parameters you'd like to update (while letting unspecified parameters inherit from the currently active ancestor states).

A map of the parameters that will be sent to the state, will populate `$stateParams.`
 Any parameters that are not specified will be inherited from currently defined parameters. Only parameters specified in the state definition can be overridden, new parameters will be ignored. This allows, for example, going to a sibling state that shares parameters specified in a parent state. Parameter inheritance only works between common ancestor states, I.e. transitioning to a sibling will get you the parameters for all parents, transitioning to a child will get you all current parameters, etc.
so you need to pass the options like this

```
$state.go("ShowMap",
           {
             data: d
           },
           {inherit:false,relative:$state} );
```

Comment: Yes, I can understand. However this not solve my problem. I don't understand why the map of gmap is not rendered anymore when I pass to a state (an html page) to another page (an html page) via $state.go(...)

Comment: @xdevel2000  how ever here the `dom` `div` with `id` `map`is replaced at the first render of the  html just check that once ...